# Rails Server Error - Fail after Gem Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to make a contact form using [this site](http://www.frick-web.com/en/blog/contact-form-gem-for-rails3)

I made it to mount ContactForm then ran bundle update and bundle install. Now I am unable to start the rails server. I get this error:

```
Error: Command not recognized
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

I have used git to checkout my last working copy of the app but I still am unable to start the rails server and have tried searching for answers online, unsuccessfully. Please help. I do not know how to continue to work on my website.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to respond. I tried first updating my Gemfile to the specific versions I know I was using before the rails server failed to respond. I had no luck there. Then I just uninstalled every gem and reinstalled them all and was able to get it up and running again. Mystery to me, but solved.